# Nudging the garbage collector in C#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Garbage Collection: Is it necessary to set large objects to null in a Dispose method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950/garbage-collection-is-it-necessary-to-set-large-objects-to-null-in-a-dispose-met)

Does anyone know if explicitly de-referencing an object;

```
 finalResults = null;
```

gives the garbage collector any more of a nudge to clean up? I have a rather large object (not huge, but big enough that I don't want it hanging around for too long after it's been used)

Would the above help or is it pointless code? I am specifically avoiding programatically talking to the GC itself, I just need to know if the above would act as any sort of prompt/hint to it.

Comment: Setting a variable to null does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Is that a temporary var?

Comment: I think you can be pretty confident that the garbage collector is clever enough that it makes no difference.

Comment: In tradition of the "rules of optimizations" by Michael A. Jackson, I hereby propose the rules of worrying about garbage collection: 1. Don't do it. 2. If you think you have to, go actually learn how it works and stand still in awe. 3. (For experts only) If you still think you need it, prove it.

Comment: This is a local variable, not a field, right? For fields this is necessary in some situations, for local variables it should be rarely necessary.

Comment: Aaaah... Many persons are telling "don't do it because it's bad habit"... But can it be proved?... It's terrible... And on Mono? And then I suspect that CodeInChaos and Henk are at least partially right... It's a sad sad world. The only thing I can do is change language and begin programming batch files for DOS :-)

Comment: It seems like the dupe is hardly a match here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is `finalResults = null;`  pointless?

Not enough information.

1. If `finalResults` is a local variable then it is pointless and potentially even harmful. You're just interfering with the optimizer.
2. If it is a class-member (property or field) it may be useful. Not very often but if you have a point in time where you can be very sure the value won't be used anymore then it won't hurt to set it to null.

Comment: +many for this. This is the only correct answer, because it can indeed be useful when `finalResults` is a class member.

Comment: When would setting a local variable to null be harmful?  If the local isn't used after the point where it set to null then surely this just does nothing.

Comment: Justin, Setting it to null _is_ a use and may prevent the optimizer from nulling/discarding it even earlier.

Comment: We should not be concerned with the lifetime of objects. The GC will do this for us. If you care that much about memory, maybe you should consider a non-managed environment.

Comment: @Henk: Fair point regarding class members.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, not really.

The main rule the garbage collector uses (to work out if it needs to do a collection) is to work out if there is enough space in the Gen-0 heap to allocate a new object when it's asked for. If it can't allocate the object, it then performs a collection.

Collections are messy and noisy (because of heap compression, promotion from objects from Gen--0 to Gen-1 and Gen-1 to Gen-2) so it's best to leave the GC to worry about it.

The GC will finalize your object when it needs to, so don't worry about it sitting around.

If you're really concerned, then in a debug build try putting a call to

```
GC.Collect();
```

Where you'd set the object to Null, and see what affect it has, but really my best advise is to not lose any sleep about it.

Comment: Don't call `GC.Collect()` unless you **really** know what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

Don't spend any time setting variables to null. It does nothing to "nudge" the garbage collector.

The whole point of having a GC is that you don't need to worry about object lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a variable to null is only of value of the C# compiler can not work out it's self that it is not going to be used again.

In well writen clear code there are very few cases when the c# compiler can not track the last time a local variable  is used it's self.

Now if finalResults was a field, it would be a different case.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are correct, but nobody seems to be making this distinction, so I will:

It depends on how `finalResults` was declared.  If it's a local variable that was declared in a method, then there will be no effect at all;  the object it was referencing would be eligible for garbage collection when the method goes out of scope in any case (and it will still be up to the garbage collector to figure out when it wants to clean up).

If, however, `finalResults` was a class field, or property, then it's a slightly different scenario (although the small "f" seems to suggest that it is not).  In this case, the object it forms part of will hold a reference to the object referenced by `finalResults`, until it can be garbage collected itself (which happens when there's nothing holding a reference to it, in turn).  In a situation like this, you *may* actually want to set it to null, to allow for the object to be eligible for GC earlier (assuming the referencing object is still going to be around for a significant amount of time).

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated IL; you may well find that the compiler knows the variable is never referenced again, so doesn't bother to generate any code for that line, in which case you *know* there won't be a difference in behaviour.